# draw bitmap images outside onDraw function Canvas Android

Tags: android

I want to call a function to draw Bitmap images from the onDraw().
Actually I need to draw bitmap images outside the onDraw() .
Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a bitmap by using below code:

```
ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_coloring_figure);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImage.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = drawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(_alteredBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
    mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now for creating bitmap, there are different methods depending on the source of image. Here I am setting image to an ImageView and creating a bitmap from that image and drawing it on canvas.

**EDIT:**
Alright, from your last comment, I came to know exactly what you want. [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50925/30391) is a good example with the use of `SurfaceView`. And if you are a beginner in Game programming, you can go through this [tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/game-development-tutorial.html) step by step.

Comment: And if I need to move the bitmap image in the canvas then how should I use thread in that case?

Comment: What do you mean move the bitmap, please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Means I want to move the image contained in the bitmap.Like in any game the background of the game theme moves automatically.I just want to move the background continuously...

Comment: Okay, check the EDIT part in my answer.